# Show/Hide UIImageview with collapse/expand space xamarin.ios mvvmcross

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am developing an iOS native app using xamarin. My app contains an UIImageView  and a "Remove" button associated with that image for **preview** purpose. These both ImageView and Remove button is initially hidden.  I have another button for selecting picture. so once, user select a photo, it will be display in ImageView and Remove button also appear dynamically. I achieve this through MvvmCross command binding.

The Problem is, when the PreviewImage and button are hidden, then also the screen occupies the blank space. I want it to be collapse, as there is nothing at that time.

So can anyone knows how to handle such situation? I am newby in iOS and xamarin.

Comment: One way to do this is to design your UI using constraints. Another is to manually write the layout changing code. For a small intro to constraints, see Cirrious.FluentLayout

Comment: i am already Design my UI using constraints.But still no luck. Thanks for suggesting fluent layout. I will look into it. Also i have another question how to move scrollview when a keyboard appear on field. Bcoz keyboard hides the control.

Comment: You could try binding the `Height` rather than the `Visibility` - then your constrains will update the layout. These are general `iOS` layout questions really - so you might have more luck asking about them wiht more general tags rather than asking about them using `Mvvm` tags